# How to read object value in php server side

Tags: php

JavaScript code

```
function addSupplier(supplier) {
    alert(supplier.name);
    alert(supplier.mobile);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(REST_SERVICE_URI, supplier)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while creating Supplier');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

PHP CODE

```
/*Create New Supplier*/
$app->post('/suppliers', function() use ($app) {
    // check for required params
    //verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'mobile'));
    $response = array();
    $name = $app->request->post($supplier->name);
    $mobile = $app->request->post($supplier->mobile);

    $db = new DbHandler();
    $supplier_id = $db->createSupplier($name, $mobile);

    if ($supplier_id != NULL) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Supplier created successfully";
        $response["supplier_id"] = $supplier_id;
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Failed to create supplier. Please try again";
    }
    echoRespnse(201, $response);
});
```

I want to read supplier.name and supplier.mobile in PHP. The above code is not working.

Comment: `$app->request->post('name')` and `$app->request->post('mobile')` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

One is that you need to read the parameter that has been passed, which is probably

```
// check for required params
verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'mobile'));

$name = $app->request->post('name');
$mobile = $app->request->post('mobile');
```

...as `$supplier` is not defined where you used it.

The second problem is that you are **not** checking for logic errors. The second function you use in the `then()` will only fire in case of a HTTP error.

But from a HTTP point of view, this is a **correct** response:

```
 {
     error  : true,
     message: 'Failed to create Supplier'
 }
```

so you need to check for this in your response handler. Also, the value you attempt to return ("data") is not actually supplied by PHP, so you must return something else (I'm guessing the supplier ID):

```
function (response) {
    var msg;
    if (!response.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
        console.error('unexpected server response', response);
        deferred.reject({ error: true, message: 'Bad server response' });
        return;
    }
    if (response.error) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
            msg = response.message;
        } else {
            console.error('missing server error message', response);
            msg = 'unknown error';
        }
        deferred.reject({ error: true, message: msg);
        return;
    }
    // Here the supplier ID is finally known.
    deferred.resolve({ error: false, id: response.supplier_id });
```